# Picking contours using the mouse?

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse, contour

My project takes a bitmap snapshot of the client area of a given window, and converts this data into an `IplImage` instance. Then after a grayscale conversion, threshing etc, bounding boxes are drawn around any contours which exceed a given minimum size (area volume).
The result is then shown within a `cvNamedWindow`

All I need to do now is allow the user to click within these rects to effectively "choose" this contour, so that the application can then extract the subrect as a new image and save it to disk.

How can this be achieved using OpenCV in C++?

Comment: Why are you using IplImage (C) and not cv::Mat (C++)?

Comment: @hetepeperfan Well to be perfectly honest I'm a bit confused about the differences between the C and C++ implementations (and versions), and how several code samples appear to reference OpenCV functions which my compiler fails to find, as well as if those functions themselves are strictly C or C++ implementations and which version of OpenCV they belong to. So at least while I'm learning OpenCV, I'm simply using "what works" for me... And for the most part, that includes the use of `IplImage` over `cv::Mat`, even though I've read that you aren't supposed to mix the implementations together.

Comment: @hetepeperfan And in a nutshell, I find OpenCV's documentation to be incredibly vague.

Comment: Unfortunately there are indeed many examples that still use the old IplImage implementation. To learn the basics of OpenCV this is not easy and indeed the documentation is not helping. The O' Reilly book written by Gary Bradski is a nice one to get started with, but this book also uses the old c implementation. You can find at least some explanation (and other tutorials) here: http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/opencvs-c-interface/

Comment: I have to agree, that it is a bit of a pitty there isn't a recent book that describes the C++ api very well(as far as I know). But the c++ functions map very well to the c functions but use cv::Mat instead of CvMat or IplImage. but as noted in the answer you accepted once you get the hang of it, it might be a blessing.

Comment: @hetepeperfan Thanks, I'll try to make the switch after a few tests.

Comment: New link: http://aishack.in/tutorials/opencvs-c-interface/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your bounding boxes you can check in a for loop in a mouse event handler if a box is clicked and which box is clicked. The code for creating a mouse event:

```
cvNamedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvSetMouseCallback("MyWindow", mouseEvent, 0);
imshow("MyWindow", image);

void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void *param) {
    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    }
}
```

You can probably find out yourself how to check if these coordinates are within a bounding box. I would also recommend to use the C++ API, as stated in the comments, as it is much easier once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else was interested on how to actually extract the chosen image,
here's how I was able to do it:

```
inline
IplImage* getSubImage(IplImage *image, CvRect region)
{
    cvSetImageROI(image, region);
    IplImage *imgRet = cvCreateImage( cvSize(region.width, region.height), image->depth, image->nChannels );
    cvCopy(image, imgRet);
    cvResetImageROI(image);
    return imgRet;
}

inline
bool pointInRect(const int x, const int y, const CvRect& r)
{
    return (
        (x > r.x) && (x < (r.x + r.width)) &&
        (y > r.y) && (y < (r.y + r.height))
    );
}

void onMouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        // boundingBoxes is declared as a vector of CvRects and
        //    filled in the main loop using cvBoundingRect(contour)
        for(UINT i = 0; i < boundingBoxes.size(); i++)
        {
            CvRect rect = boundingBoxes[i].rect;
            if( pointInRect(x, y, rect) )
            {
                IplImage* img = getSubImage(imgSource, rect);
                // Do whatever you want with the sub-image here
                cvNamedWindow("Selection");
                cvShowImage("Selection", img);
                cvReleaseImage(&img);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```